# Creating a QBOE Time Entry App for Win 8

Tags: windows-8, quickbooks-online

My company uses Quick Books Online for its accounting, and that's where we go to log our time against projects. In an effort to make time entry easier, and a way to learn how to write a Windows 8 Metro app, I thought it would be a useful project that simplified time tracking, application that could automatically submit my time to QB. The thought would be users would use their own QBO logins so it would be able to see their time entries.

I have been looking around the api for QBOE and can't seem to tell if its possible to connect to a QBOE account with non admin credentials. Is what I am thinking even possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You will need something in the middle to talk between QB and your application.

There are a number of different timesheet apps on appcenter that you might look at. https://appcenter.intuit.com/category/time-tracking

Comment: So my option would be to have the QB admin add the app in the allowed applications and it would be on the users to make sure they add time entries under the correct user?